# Differentiate between basic and binomial probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

So I saw a question under the topic for Binomial Distributions which asks that what is the probability of making 4 out of 7 free throws where the $P(making a free throw) = 0.7$. Why can't the answer be a simple $ (0.7)^4 $? Why would it be $7C4 * (0.7)^4 * (0.3)^3$?

Apologies if this sounds like a dumb question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a dumb question, first and foremost. The probability you described, $0.7^4$, the probability of making four free-throws in a row. However, if you shoot $7$ times, and you make $4$ of them, you must also miss three of them (hence the $.3^3$). Additionally, you need to take care of the order in which you made them: you can miss the first three and then make the last four, or make two then miss three then make two, etc. It turns out that the number of ways you can make four shots out of $7$ is:

$$7\mathcal{C}4=35$$

You can figure this out yourself (the "hard" way) by drawing $7$ dashes on a piece of paper and filling it in with $x$ for a make and $0$ for a miss. You can repeat this until you've come up with all of the combinations. The mathematical intuition behind it is that, if you have seven spots, you need to choose $4$ to fill with successes, thus $7\mathcal{C}4$. This is the same as picking the misses as well, since:

$$7\mathcal{C}3=35$$

as well. Hope this clears it up a bit.

Comment: I understand what you're saying and I had this confusion because initially when you start out with probability, you have questions likes what is the probability of flipping a fair coin 3 times and getting 3 heads is essentially $(0.5)^3$. But it also gives the same answer with the Binomial distribution formula. So does this mean that the initial exercises just simplify things? And any finite number of independent trials with a boolean outcome where the probability for each outcome stays constant can be classified as a Binomial experiment?

Comment: The pmf of a binomial distribution will essentially be the answer to any of these types of questions (within a certain degree of complexity, of course). I hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

Doing $(0.7)^4$ ignores the fact that you have three free throws that were not successful.

$(0.7)^4$ is merely the probability of making 4 free throws period, with no additional information added.

For you to obtain 4 successful free throws and 3 unsuccessful ones, you would have $(0.7)^4(0.3)^3$ by independence, but note that there are $\binom{7}{4}$ ways this would occur, hence we have $\binom{7}{4}(0.7)^4(0.3)^3$.